# What function space fits best in describing fields in field theory?

Tags: field-theory, mathematics, classical-field-theory

**Question:** Is there a proper mathematical space in which (at least most) of the (classical) fields treated by physicists belong?

In other words, when a textbook says "Let $\phi_{i}(x)$ be a field", is that a mathematical space (a "field space") which one can think of in order give some mathematical concreteness rather than treat these objects on the basis of one's physical intuition of what a field could be?

I believe a proper space of fields could be something like $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, the space of rapid decrease functions, since functions on this space are $C^{\infty}$ and have sufficient regularity at $|x| \to \infty$, but maybe one needs a more general setting than this.

Answer (score 2):

In general the space of fields can be thought of as the space of sections of some (usually vector) bundle over your spacetime manifold. The situation in physics is, however, a little more complicated as OP sort of hints at in the question because boundary conditions do play a role. The most common boundary conditions, because spacetime is usually taken to be non-compact, involve fall-off condition where the fields need to go to zero at infinity.

This is, however, not always the case. The real fall-off conditions are usually given by a finiteness of energy/action requirement. For gauge fields, this means that the field strength tensor must vanish, and hence the gauge connection itself only needs to approach a pure gauge configuration at infinity.